# Janusys.com or Janusus.net Website and Forum

Tags: windows, winforms, controls, janus, gridex

is there anybody who preserved the old Website of the Janusys company. Mostly known for their **GridEX** Winforms control but they had a complete suite of Winform Tools. Their support was (up until 'bankruptcy') very good and gave much more info on how to use their control in a non standard way.
I still use their components a lot in my projects and up until last year there was still a lookup method on http://janusys.net to get ideas if I was stuck.
The site(s) are out of the air now, so I hope someone has made a 'copy'??

regards Sandor

Comment: I hope so too...

Comment: Their timeline control was unparalleled.

Comment: @Sandor Did Janus go bankrupt?  When was it? (I'm trying to put together a case to remove it from an old product, and need ammunition).

Comment: Yep about 3 years ago